# ASP.NET web app confirmation box - Button.Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 web app that contains a form where the user can add some data and I have a button that I want to save the data in the database.

When the user presses this button, the first thing I do is search if there already exists a record for a specific item. If there is, I want to show a confirmation box where I'm letting the user know: "*This record already exists. Do you want to update it?*". If the user presses **YES**, I want to do an `UPDATE`, else I will do an `INSERT`. The problem is with this damn confirmation box.

What I have so far:

In *aspx.cs*:

```
public void OnConfirm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
    if (confirmValue == "Yes")
    {
    Response.Write("YES");
    }
    else
    {
    Response.Write("NO");
    }
}
```

In *aspx* I have:

```
<script>
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Record already exists. Do you want to update it?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>
```

and I added a button:

```
<asp:Button ID="alertBtn" runat="server" OnClientClick = "Confirm()" OnClick="OnConfirm" Text="" style="display:none"/>
```

If I remove the style and run the app, when I click on this button it works perfectly. The confirmation box shows up, when I click **YES** it calls a function, when I click **NO** it calls another function.

But how do I click on this button from code? Nothing works!

I tried with:

```
1) alertBtn.Click += new EventHandler(this.OnConfirm);// doesn't do anything
2) ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "somekey", "Confirm();", true);// I was only able to run the Confirm() method, but it didn't call the OnConfirm method which is on the server. 
3) Following step 2, I tried adding a call from js to c# in the Confirm() method: document.getElementById('<%=alertBtn%>).OnClick   // this didn't work either
```

So I just want to do a Button.Click from code behind in order to trigger the Confirm() method which will open a confirmation box and after I click YES/NO, the OnConfirm method from the server should call the appropriate function based on this YES/NO value. If you have another solution besides the one with using a button, I'm open to new ideas.

### Update

To better explain my problem, I added [this demo link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Demos/233/). I want to achieve the same thing without having to click on a button, just from code.

Comment: Well both...the js code is responsible for creating the confirm box and the server code is responsible for grabbing the YES/NO input and redirecting the flow towards the appropiate method. The button seems to do just that through the OnClientClick and OnClick parameters.

Comment: I think you are trying to mix logic on the server side with logic on the client side. If you want to execute the Code in the JS Confirm Method from the Server you need to render Javascript on the Client. It is difficult to mix this. When do you want to raise the method? Maybe we can find a way to do this on the Client only. What is triggering the call? - Or at least do the Client logic first and then jump to the Server logic.

Comment: Well..I'm doing an sqlcommand on the server where I check if the current record exists in the DB. If the record already exists, that's when I want to ask the user what does it want to do. Update it ? YES/NO

Comment: But checking whether the record exists in the DB happens when the user clicks a button as well? Or when is this triggered?

Comment: Yes...after adding some data into a form, I have a save record button. When it pushes it, first thing it checks if it already exists.

Comment: From what I can see, the solution is to use: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "somekey", "Confirm();", true);  to call the JS logic...which stores the users response in a hidden field. Afterwards, I need to call a function on the server but I'm not sure how to call this function. I'm thinking of calling it from the first JS function, but I don't know if that's the right way. I tried calling it from the server and the user's response was always NO. Because I have an if/else and it always enters the else now.  Hidden field must be empty or something.

Comment: I would look for asp.net Webmethods in Google and how to call them from the Client via Javascript.

Comment: I already tried the WebMethod but this just moves the C# method to javascript. It is useful for avoiding postbacks. But in my case I have a javascript method Confirm which stores the users input (YES/NO) on a hidden field. What I want is to get this hidden field on the server and do a switch based on it's value. string confirmValue= Request.Form["hiddenField_name"]; //This is how I'm trying to access the hiddenfield but I think that it doesn't persist after the postback from the button.Aaa..so here is where WebMethod would come in use. But in WebMehot I can't use Request.Form to get the field